# How do I create a white rectangle in Unity 2D?

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine

Hello Stack Overflow community.

I've just started to use Unity to port my video game to multiple platforms.  I had a question about creating objects programmatically in Unity.  This is what it my game looks like currently:

[image]

When the user taps the camera button, the camera picture scales bigger onTap and offTap.  I want the **entire screen to flash white for only a brief second** but I have no idea how to do this.  Here is the C# code I have already for this question:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class question3 : MonoBehaviour {
    int cameraTaps = 0;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    IEnumerator CameraCoroutine() {
        Debug.Log("Before Waiting 3 seconds");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        Debug.Log("After Waiting 3 Seconds");
        Application.LoadLevel("question4");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "camera")
                {
                    var camera = (hit.collider.gameObject);
                    camera.transform.localScale += new Vector3(.1f, .1f, 0);
                }
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "camera")
                {
                    var camera = (hit.collider.gameObject);
                    camera.transform.localScale -= new Vector3(.1f, .1f, 0);
                    cameraTaps = cameraTaps + 1;
                    print (cameraTaps);
                    if (cameraTaps == 5)
                    {
                        StartCoroutine(CameraCoroutine());

                    }
                    if (cameraTaps > 5)
                    {
                        Application.LoadLevel("fail");
                    }

                }
                if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "turtle")
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I really have no idea how to either insert PNG's or create a rectangle that will overlay for a brief second.

Comment: Do you need input during that time?  If not, you could create an object with an OnGUI that draws a full screen white rect until you don't need it and then hide or destroy the gameObject.  If you need interactivity during the whiteout, you can create an object with a vertex shader that draws a full screen quad and attach it to a Unity quad object.

Comment: I don't need any input. Basically I need the entire screen to flash white for a second.  The whole screen should flash white on GetMouseButtonUp every time the hit.collider is activated. Could you help me? I'm very new to unity and I don't understand how I could write that code :D

Comment: All you really need to do is create a unity quad and attach it to your camera so that it renders in front of everything else. Give it a simple shader such as Unlit and position it so it covers the camera viewport completely (you can parent it to the camera so it follows the camera all the time).  Then just enable/disable it from script

Comment: Could you post some code to answer the question? Plz :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an old question, never the less I'm here with 2 solutions for you: (These were coded up in C#)

Solution #1: Is exactly what you have asked for in code format. I'm fairly certain you already solved this issue (but this is for anyone else who stumbles upon this problem).

```
//bFlashed is a boolean (you can name it what ever you like)
void OnGUI()
{
    if (bFlashed)
    {
        Texture2D tx2DFlash = new Texture2D(1,1); //Creates 2D texture
        tx2DFlash.SetPixel(1,1,Color.white); //Sets the 1 pixel to be white
        tx2DFlash.Apply(); //Applies all the changes made
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), tx2DFlash); //Draws the texture for the entire screen (width, height)
        StartCoroutine(SetFlashFalse());
    }
}
IEnumerator SetFlashFalse()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //Waits 1 second before setting boolean to false
    bFlashed = false;
}
```

Another way is to actually mess about with Unity's lights. This is personally my favorite option because you'll be able to manipulate the location of the light, intensity, range (if using spot/point light), color, and many more options.

For the following solution I attached a simple Light component to the Main Camera.

- Type: Directional
- Color: White
- Intensity: 8
- Enabled: False

Solution #2: Just call `StartCoroutine(CameraFlash());` when you want the flash to occur

```
IEnumerator CameraFlash() //You can name this however you like
{
    //Wait for 1/4 of a second (maybe you want a small sound to play before screen flashes)
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.25f);
    //Gets the light component from Main Camera
    Light cameraFlash = GameObject.FindWithTag("MainCamera").GetComponent<Light>();
    //Enable the cameras Flash
    cameraFlash.enabled = true;

    //This will decrease the intensity every 0.05 of a second by 2
    for (float f = 8; f >= 0; f -= 2)
    {
        cameraFlash.intensity = f; //Intensity takes in a float so you can really change this up nicely
        //Just be sure that it sets to 0.0f at some point (so that there is no more excess light
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);
    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2); 
    cameraFlash.enabled = false; //Be sure to disable it again (until you need it)
    cameraFlash.intensity = 8; //And reset the intensity back to 8
}
```